# Using javascript to click an embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onmouseup

I'd like to click on an embedded youtube video using javascript (so the video plays automatically). I successfully simulated a click on a `<div>` like this:

```
function f(){
    alert("hello");
}

<div id="someid" onmouseup="f();">
    my text
</d>

document.getElementById("someid").onmouseup();
```

**How can the above code be adapted to work with an embedded youtube video?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `&autoplay=1` to the link of the video in the `<embed>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

If he does what you suggest the views on the embedded video won't count.  I'm pretty sure he is asking his question because he is trying to find a way to get the video to autoplay and have youtube count the views at the same time.